# What is the significance of text color in Java? (why is public/private = red | class = cyan)

Tags: java, text, colors, command

I am extremely new to coding (today marks day one of my official journey to become a proficient Java coder).

I am curious as to why there are different colors for different tasks within the Java language.  What does each text color signify?

I feel as if this is a simple question I just don't know it.

n/a

```
public class Pong extends JFrame {
(red) (cyan)(Green)(red) (green)
```

Comment: color is due to the software you're using, not to the language. Often a color is related to one thing (keywords for example). But it does not affect at all the code

Comment: There are no fixed colors in Java. It is just normal unformatted text. What you are experiencing is just [Syntax Highlighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_highlighting)

Comment: You can write Java code or any other language in notepad / textedit and it will work / compile just as fine.

Answer (score 9):

The colors have nothing to do with the language itself.  They're used by your IDE (Integrated Development Environment, i.e. the program that you used to edit your code) to make the code more readable.  There's no significance to the specific colors used, and the IDE will have options somewhere to change the coloring to whatever you like.

Answer (score 1):

The colors mean nothing, it's just your IDE highlighting different keywords to make your code easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking how an advanced editor/IDE uses different colors for different syntax elements.

If so: those are not properties of the languages. There is no standard that tells IDE developers to use this or that color schema. They simply decided to use this or that color for this or that syntax element.

Of course, most tools that do that ... the people creating them spend a lot of time to define coloring schemas that helps readers to read/understand source code quickly.

Answer (score 0):

the code styling is not related to language itself, its more about the IDE you're using. for example in case of netbeans, have a look at [this](https://ui.netbeans.org/docs/ui/editor_fonts_colors/Editor_fonts_and_colors.htm)